# The getter 'uid' was called on null - but only half the time

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

So I have this screen in my Flutter app that is supposed to show all the notes for a particular user. I have the Firestore structured so that there is a collection of notes and each user has one document named their uid. Then all their notes are store in a collection (usernotes) under their document.

The problem I am having here is that when you try to access the notes page in the app, you get the error

The getter 'uid' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: uid

But when I simply click run from the Flutter app, everything works just fine. You can see all the notes on the screen. Here is my note screen.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'welcome_screen.dart';

class NoteScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'note_screen';

  @override
  _NoteScreenState createState() => _NoteScreenState();
}

class _NoteScreenState extends State<NoteScreen> {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  User loggedInUser;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
  }

  void getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      final user = await _auth.currentUser;
      if (user != null) {
        loggedInUser = user;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Field Notes'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.chat),
            tooltip: 'Messages',
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
            tooltip: 'Log Out',
            onPressed: () {
              _auth.signOut();
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, WelcomeScreen.id);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('notes').doc(loggedInUser.uid).collection('usernotes')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (ctx, streamSnapShot) {
          if(!streamSnapShot.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');
          if (streamSnapShot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          final noteData = streamSnapShot.data.docs;
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: noteData.length,
            itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: Text(noteData[index]['text']),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton:
          FloatingActionButton(child: Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: () {
            FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('notes').doc(loggedInUser.uid).collection('usernotes').add({
              'text' : 'This was added by clicking the button!'
            });
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Build method called before calling the await _auth.currentUser. This is the reason loggedInUser.uid was called on null.

Comment: I don't understand how that works. My await _auth.currentUser is above the build method.

Comment: According to updated plugin of firebase auth you do't need to get current user using await simply use _auth.currentUser.uid. if you have latest version of  firebase auth.

Comment: Not sure why this question was downvoted. How can I improve the question? What is wrong with my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`currentUser` is of type `User` therefore you do not need to use `await` since it doesn't return a `Future`. You can do the following:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('notes').doc(_auth.currentUser.uid).collection('usernotes').snapshots(),
```

And:

```
FloatingActionButton(child: Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: () {
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('notes').doc(_auth.currentUser.uid).collection('usernotes').add({'text' : 'This was added by clicking the button!'});
});
```